# Как изменить размер ползунка скролла в css?

Tags: html, css

У меня есть блок в котором указаны свойства максимальной высоты max-height:300px; и overflow-y: auto; Можно ли сделать размер ползунка полосы прокрутки фиксированным? Сейчас его высота зависит от контента внутри блока, а нужно чтобы он был (например 50px) высоты независимо от контента внутри блока. Пытался найти какую-нибудь информацию в интернете, но особо информации не нашёл

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы можете использовать js плагин для этого. например, [jQuery custom content scroller](http://manos.malihu.gr/jquery-custom-content-scroller/)

В данном случаи высота движка задается в классе `.mCSB_dragger`

```js
(function($){
    $(window).on("load",function(){
        $(".block").mCustomScrollbar({
          theme: "dark",
        });
    });
})(jQuery);
```

```css
.block {
  max-height:300px;
  overflow-y: auto;
  width: 300px;
}

.mCSB_dragger{ 
  height: 50px!important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.mcustomscrollbar/3.0.6/jquery.mCustomScrollbar.concat.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.mcustomscrollbar/3.0.6/jquery.mCustomScrollbar.min.css">
<div class="block">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.Lorem Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.Lorem </div>
```